# Authentication manager missing in custom security class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I have a security jar that I am implementing in my project. I am extending the `BasicSecurityConfig` which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and has all the filters. I was told that all I need is to extend the `BasicSecurityConfig` and call `super().configure` which will call the parent's configure method. However, I am getting this error,

```
Field authenticationManager in com.custom.security.CustomSecurityFilter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.
```

The parent class already has an `AuthenticationManager` bean, I shouldn't need to define it in the child class too.

`My Security` Class

```
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends BasicSecurityConfig {

    private static final String PAYMONEYROLE = "(hasRole('EE'))";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // must call super first
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1/cart/validate").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1/cart/validate").access(PAYMONEYROLE)
                .and().cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean invalidResourceFilterRegistration(InvalidResourceFilter invalidResourceFilter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(invalidResourceFilter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        invalidResourceFilter.setDisabled(true);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean customSecurityFilterRegistration(CustomSecurityFilter customSecurityFilter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(customSecurityFilter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);

        return registration;
    }
   
}
```

`Custom Security` Jar

```
    public class BasicSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired
    private InvalidResourceFilter invalidResourceFilter;

    public BasicSecurityConfig() {
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ((HttpSecurity)((HttpSecurity)http.addFilterBefore(this.customSecurityFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class).addFilterAfter(this.invalidResourceFilter, FilterSecurityInterceptor.class).sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()).exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint()).accessDeniedHandler(this.customDeniedHandler()).and()).authorizeRequests().accessDecisionManager(this.accessDecisionManager());
    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(new String[]{"/docs**/**", "/swagger-ui.html**/**", "/webjars**/**", "/swagger-resources**/**", "/api-docs**/**", "/v2/api-docs**", "/version.json**"});
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.customAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        return new CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomSecurityFilter customSecurityFilter() {
        return new CustomSecurityFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler customDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomSystemUserAuthVoter customSystemUserAuthVoter() {
        return new CustomSystemUserAuthVoter();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter() {
        WebExpressionVoter wev = new WebExpressionVoter();
        wev.setExpressionHandler(this.defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler());
        return wev;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        return new ExplicitDecisionManager(Arrays.asList(this.customSystemUserAuthVoter(), this.webExpressionVoter()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- As per your error, `CustomSecurityFilter` is supposed to have `authenticationManager` injected. But it is created without `authenticationManager` as below.

```
   @Bean
   public CustomSecurityFilter customSecurityFilter() {
    return new CustomSecurityFilter();
   }
```

- If you can modify `BasicSecurityConfig`, then update the method as follows:

```
   @Bean
   public CustomSecurityFilter customSecurityFilter() {
      //If it has a constructor which accept AuthenticationManager
      return new CustomSecurityFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
      //If it has a setter for AuthenticationManager instead
      CustomSecurityFilter filter = new CustomSecurityFilter();
      filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
      return filter;
   }
```

- If you cannot modify `BasicSecurityConfig`, then create it in `SecurityConfiguration` with `Primary`

```
   @Bean
   @Primary
   public CustomSecurityFilter customSecurityFilter() {
      //If it has a constructor which accept AuthenticationManager
      return new CustomSecurityFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
      //If it has a setter for AuthenticationManager instead
      CustomSecurityFilter filter = new CustomSecurityFilter();
      filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
      return filter;
   }
```